# Create a custom modifier key to write special characters

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, customization

I have a Macbook with a [Japanese keyboard](http://xahlee.info/kbd/ilayout/Apple_keyboard_Japan.jpg), but don't need to write Japanese. I do prefer a US layout, but need to write German characters (äöüÄÖÜß). On Windows they had a "US - International" layout for this, where you can use for example <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> for <kbd>ö</kbd>, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> for <kbd>ä</kbd> and so on.

I know I can do this on Mac by pressing <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> then press <kbd>a</kbd> for <kbd>ä</kbd>, but this is too slow to type fast with.

Is there a way for me to create this using a custom modifier?
I'd like to make the <kbd>かな</kbd> key right of the space bar a modifier key. So I'd press <kbd>かな</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> to get <kbd>ö</kbd> for example.

I have remapped a few keys on my keyboard via hidutil, for example to extend the right shift and backspace to the character left of it. But can't find a way to press multiple keys to type one character

Comment: "But can't find a way to press multiple keys to type one character" - without modifier key you can use Text Replacement feature. Choose combination of keypresses which occur rarely in your language (for example jj -> ä).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's input source US International PC may do what you want as it is.  Below is the layout for a JIS keyboard.  Umlauts are made by pressing Shift on the orange key and then the base letter.

In any case it would be easy to make something closer with [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/).

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wpi1kat7gmeifj3/Win%20US%20Intl.keylayout?dl=0) is a version I made a few years ago which conforms to Windows US International's Option level.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I know about the first part and mentioned in my question that that's a bit too slow. I've now modified the layout from your dropbox and also replaced the かな with option via hidutil. This seems like a good setup for me now, thanks